# Ruby Rails: In an Ebay like application, how might I Accept and Confirm a Bid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I'm confused as to how the table structure needs to be set up to do this. An item has a bid and the bid belongs to the item. The person who accepts the bid on the item needs to be the owner of the item. I don't know how to pass the Item owner's ID through to my bid accepting function.

Comment: As you see from the variety of answers leading in fundamentally different direction, your question should be a lot more precise. You are actually not only asking for a table structure here, you are asking for how the models look like, the migrations that lead to the table structure, the associations between the models, the controller actions and links in the view that allow a user to bid on some item, and the controller actions and links in the view that allow an owner to accept bid. That is far too much for a stackoverflow question, please break it down and ask for precise help along the way.

Comment: Agreed. I should have made a narrower question. Luckily I solved the problem myself not long after posting here. My head was just foggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a bid has an item and an item has an owner you should be able to query the owner from the bid

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bids
   has_one :owner
end

class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :item
end
```

Something like so:

```
bid.item.owner
```

and then check that the owner is the submitter

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass `user_id` to `accept` method. All you need is to make sure that someone that is trying to accept is entitled to do that.

Easy way may be using [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or similar gem for that.

For more complex solution you could read about [DCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data,_Context,_and_Interaction) pattern.